# Jwt token disappears after login

Tags: node.js, next.js, jwt, cors

I have a project with nextjs as front-end and seperate node.js as backend.
Front-end is on example.com and backend on api.example.com.
In my login page when i post to backend login endpoint token created and i can see it on developer tools cookies. It needs to redirect to example.com/user if res.status 200.
And example.com/user page makes a get request to backend with token in headers. But the problem is,
example.com/user page can not find jwt in cookies so can't set it in headers, so the response is 401 and redirects back to login page.
Also after login if i refresh the page, jwt is disappeared also.
I use cors in my backend app like:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "https://example.com",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
  })
);
```

and my post login endpoint like that:

```
exports.post_login = async function (req, res) {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const user = await User.findOne({ where: { username } });
  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if (!user || !isMatch) {
    return res.status(401).send("Wrong username or password");
  }
  const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "5h",
  });
  res.cookie("jwt", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "None",
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 5,
  });
  res.status(200).send({ data: user.username, token });
};
```

am i doing something wrong?

When project was in local there were no problem, when i deployed it jwt started to disappear.

I didn't try to save it in localStorage etc. because i read about it's not safe, and i believe there is another way as it was working on local